# Why Can't I deploy In-App Guidance From Change Set?

Tags: deployment, change-set

I'm having trouble deploying an active in-app guidance via a change set (dev to partial). In the change set, i've selected 'Prompts' as what to deploy, and I've included the assets that I've used (images) in the steps.  I've also activated In-App guidance in adoption settings in the target org.

I'm getting this error:

> StepNumber fields in a walkthrough must range from 1 to the number of steps in the walkthrough.

I have 6 steps in the walkthrough and I don't know what they mean by 'StepNumber' fields? Is there a setting I'm missing? Am I missing a component in my change set?  Google has failed to provide the answer! Anyone?

---

*UPDATE from OP's self-answer 2021.07.07*

Thanks for the response. I dont even know where to look for the missing step number...I have 6 steps in the prompt...and they are consecutively numbered. the documentation isn't a help. I am looking at all of this in the UI and in change sets, not in vs code or anything. I rebuilt the walk through in the target sandbox and I am going to try to push it from there to the full sandbox. hopefully it will work! if not I dont know where to go next

Answer (score 1):

This error comes directly from the API, and it's basically telling you that there's a missing number in the list of elements. This is stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_prompt.htm).

> Required for walkthroughs only. Indicates the number of the last step the user viewed or interacted with in a walkthrough. Maximum of 10 steps. Numbers must be consecutive without repeated or skipped numbers. Available in API version 49.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

This issue resolved when I deployed from our partial sandbox to our full sandbox and I was able to deploy it successfully.  Since I manually recreated the guidance walkthrough in the partial sandbox, I suspect that while creating the prompt in our dev sandbox, I may have deleted a step, so that the metadata steps were out of order.  I'm going to look into this further to satisfy my curiosity, and also, because the steps in metadata should reorder if you delete something---so that when you deploy you don't get the error.  When I manually created it in par, I didn't delete any steps.

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues deploying prompt via change set, but with a different error:`The Reference Element Context field's value must contain version: 1.`

Couldnt find any way to resolve so I opened up the prompt in vscode and saw a version value on `referenceElementContext` node that was set to 2, so I set it to 1

example:

initial:

```
 <referenceElementContext>{&quot;scope&quot;:{&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;runtime_approval_process_pendingApprovalCard1&quot;}},&quot;version&quot;:2}</referenceElementContext>
```

final:

```
 <referenceElementContext>{&quot;scope&quot;:{&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;runtime_approval_process_pendingApprovalCard1&quot;}},&quot;version&quot;:1}</referenceElementContext>
```

and i was able to deploy successfully.

perhaps something similar could be done if you run into the issue described in the original post.

the issue i had also may be due to changes in what you can target in Summer22, that were in sandbox but not in prod yet...